# strip number from beginning of line

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, split

Is there a way to strip the number and the surrounding whitespace from a line? I don't want to strip **my** whitespace though. Sometimes my code freezes, and I have to copy it with the numbers, so I am trying to make something that removes the numbers from each line

```
  9 if (5==5) {
 10     console.log('Examples rock!')
 11 else {
 12     console.log('Stuff')
 13 }
```

Line 1 would be `if (x==5) {` afterwards, with the number and spaces around it gone. I just need to be able to do it for 1 line, as I can iterate through

Is there a good regex or other method of doing this?

Comment: Why are there numbers pre-fixed on each line of code? An editor will give you line numbers.

Comment: So is this a string?

Comment: Where you writing this kind of codes? Alien spotted :P

Comment: What is x? It is a bit unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's hard. What happens if you have something like `case \n 5:`?

Comment: @Bathsheba than wouldn't the 5 would be on a new line and have a line number....

Comment: I edited my code to show why

Comment: @epascarello: Yes you might be correct; perhaps it does work assuming *every* line has a line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have a string that contains the code and line numbers, I know that happens when you copy code from some pretty print outputs in webpages

```
"  9 if (x==5) {\n\
 10     console.log('Examples rock!')\n\
 11 else {\n\
 12     console.log('Stuff')\n\
 13 }".replace(/^\s*\d+\s/gm,"");
```

explaination of reg exp

```
^   - start of line
\s* - one or more white spaces
\d+ - one or more numbers
\s  - single white space
```

---

```js
function remove () {
   document.getElementById("out").value = document.getElementById("in").value.replace(/^\s*\d+\s/gm,"");  
}
```

```css
textarea { width:100%; min-height: 100px; }
```

```html
<label for="in">Input</label>
<textarea id="in">
  9 if (5==5) {
 10     console.log('Examples rock!')
 11 else {
 12     console.log('Stuff')
 13 }
</textarea>
<button onclick="remove()">run</button>
<br/>
<label for="out">Output</label>
<textarea id="out"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the lines by using a regular expression.

```js
function stripNumbers(text) {
  return text.split('\n').map(function(line) {
    let tokens = line.match(/^\s*\d+ (.*)$/);
    return tokens && tokens.length > 0 ? tokens[1] : line;
  }).join('\n');
}

let editor = document.getElementById('editor');
editor.value = stripNumbers(editor.value);
```

```html
<textarea id="editor" rows="7" cols="72">
 9 if (x==5) {
 10     console.log('Examples rock!')
 11 else {
 12     console.log('Stuff')
 13 }
</textarea>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of checking if the length of 0?

Comment: Each line returns `null` when I run it.

Comment: @PAS Try switching `let` to `var`, might be your browser. I only use `let` cause it does not pollute the global space.

Comment: @PAS Checking length in-case a line is artificially-wrapped and does not start with a number. Also, it's good practice to check bounds. The match does not guarantee a group 1, value.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for a wide variety of cases, even if there are more than one sets of digits, assuming whatever is formatting your lines always places one space after the number.  I used sed 4.2.2, but this should work in Perl, Python, JavaScript, and others too.

```
sed -r "s/^([ \t]*[0-9])* //"
```

For JavaScript, use string.replace(re, replacement) as follows:

```js
function removeLineNumbering(line)
{
  return line.replace(/^([ \t]*[0-9])* /gm, "");
}

document.getElementById('editor').value = removeLineNumbering(editor.value);
```

```html
<textarea id="editor" rows="5" cols="50">
  9 if (x==5) {
 10     console.log('Examples rock!')
 11 else {
 12     console.log('Stuff')
 13 }
</textarea>
```